# Mongo: db.cloneCollection doesn't work in 2.4.6?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to clone a collection from one Mongo host to another:

I have two mongo instances v.2.4.6 installed on two hosts:
host1 and host2 (host1 and host2 are actually IPs but replaced with name to simplify the question). Both hosts are in the same network and I can successfully open other server's mongo console from the first server using:

on **host1**:

```
mongo --host host2
```

But when I do in the mongo shell of the first server:

on **host1**:

```
db.cloneCollection("host2:27017", "my_db.my_collection")
```

The output is:

```
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

But the `my_db` database is not created on the host1. I tried to create empty database but the collection isn't copied either. I tried to create empty collection in it, but the collection items are not copied.

Note: The `my_db.my_collection` on host2 is not empty. Have double checked that.

Guys, could you please check if the `db.cloneCollection()` works for you on mongo 2.4.6?
If so - maybe I'm missing some prerequisite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongodb for Windows, v 2.4.6

First `mongod` with default params: port -> 27017, dbpath -> c:\data\db 
Second `mongod` with params: port -> 27018, dbpath -> c:\data\db1

Logged to the second mongod. Use `test` db. Execute:

```
db.cloneCollection("localhost:27017","db.test.so000")
```

Not cloned. Then execute:

```
db.cloneCollection("localhost:27017","so000")
```

It was cloned. So, suggestion in this case -- do not use full path to collection.

**Updated**

Just investigated some documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection 
If you want to use db prefix, you should run clone this way:

```
db.runCommand({cloneCollection: "test.so000", from: "localhost:27017"})
```

It will clone collection `so000` as well. It will create db even if db `test` doesn't exist on this second server.

Comment: It works. So the idea is to do `use my_db` on the second server and then don't use db_name in the `cloneCollection` statement. Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you call "second server" ? is it the source or destination ? i would rather use terms like "source server" and "destination server"